# Error in list2env(list, envir = .GlobalEnv) : names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x

Tags: r, list, dataframe, environment-variables, names

I am trying to unlist a list of dataframes into R environment after adding a new column to each df,
I would like to keep the same name for all dataframes.

My current code:

```
df_list <- list(CONCE84.dbf, CONCE89.dbf, CONCE92.dbf, CONCE94.dbf,
                CONCE96.dbf, CONCE98.dbf, CONCE00.dbf, CONCE02.dbf,
                CONCE04.dbf, CONCE05.dbf, CONCE06.dbf, CONCE08.dbf,
                CONCE10.dbf, CONCE12.dbf, CONCE14.dbf, CONCE16.dbf,
                CONCE18.dbf)


df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(decil) {
  
  mutate(decil,
         decil = ntile(gascor, 10))
  
})

## unlisting list to dfs ##
list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)

## console output ##
Error in list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

Comment: Why do you want to write them back to the global environment? You should keep them in a list, for all sorts of reasons. For one, as you have demonstrated yourself, it makes it far easier to perform manipulations on them. Ask yourself _why_ do you need them in the global environment?

Comment: If by some highly unlikely set of circumstances it is _really_ better to write them back to the global environment you can try `list2env('names<-'(df_list, ls(pattern = "CONCE\\d\\d\\.dbf")), envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @AllanCameron I think `setNames()` is a bit friendlier than `names<-`, but agree the data would be much easier to work with if just left inside the list.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments by [Allan Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron) and improved by [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick), you can set the names on the fly with `setNames`:

```
list2env(setNames(df_list, ls(pattern = "CONCE\\d\\d\\.dbf")), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is a result of passing a list without names, so you must write the names of your dataframes before using `list2env()` function:

```
names(df_list) <- c("CONCE84.dbf", "CONCE89.dbf", "CONCE92.dbf", "CONCE94.dbf",
                    "CONCE96.dbf", "CONCE98.dbf", "CONCE00.dbf", "CONCE02.dbf",
                    "CONCE04.dbf", "CONCE05.dbf", "CONCE06.dbf", "CONCE08.dbf",
                    "CONCE10.dbf", "CONCE12.dbf", "CONCE14.dbf", "CONCE16.dbf",
                    "CONCE18.dbf")

list2env(df_list ,.GlobalEnv)
```