# Unlist a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of dataframes that I have created using

```
list_dataframes = list(dataframe_1, dataframe_2...)
```

And now I wonder how to unlist this list.

I have searched for it and found this solution:

```
list2env(list_dataframes ,.GlobalEnv)
```

in this old question: [Unlist a list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697239/unlist-a-list-of-dataframes)

However, when using that solution, the following error arises:

```
Error in list2env(list_dataframes, .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

Any idea why it's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be a named list i.e. list(dataframe_1 = dataframe_1, ...`

Comment: Why exactly do you want to unlist your list? It's normally much easier to work with data in a list rather than clobber your global environment with a bunch of variables. You might just be making things more difficult for yourself.

Comment: Absolutely correct @akrun. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's only a matter of convinience for me @MrFlick

Comment: Likely duplicate: [Error in list2env(list, envir = .GlobalEnv) : names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63906806/13095326)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a result of passing a list without names

```
list2env(list(1, 2, 3), .GlobalEnv)
```

> Error in list2env(list(1, 2, 3), .GlobalEnv) :    names(x) must be a
> character vector of the same length as x

```
list2env(list(a= 1, b = 2, c = 3), .GlobalEnv)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```